# Present perfect vs past perfect

Tags: tense

What I like about her is that she never gives up- after an exam had not gone well, she just goes ahead with renewed zeal .

Is the sentence correct? I m confused about the clause-(after an exam had not gone well).Should it be -(after an exam has not gone well)?

Answer (score 1):

If you will excuse the pun, your sentence presents a perfect example of the present-perfect.  The time (some point after the test) is considered in the present, and the test's "going" is complete.  Therefore you write

> After an exam has not gone well, she just goes ahead with renewed zeal.

(Incidentally, you are using the same word, *go*, in two different senses.  That borders on [syllepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis) and is probably not a good stylistic choice in any language.  How about "she carries on" or "she returns to work"?)

**Edit:** In all the cases I could think of, the [aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) of verb in the subordinate clause has to match the main verb, *even where it patently makes no sense*.

> After he exercises, he showers.

Logically, it should be "exercised", because it happened before the present-time of the shower -- but no native English speaker would say "exercised" in that context.  At most, you can use present-perfect, "after he has exercised".

What can I tell you?  English is weird.

Comment: Is the above sentence is right?.When I used past perfect tense with present indefinite.Or is it possible to have past perfect tense with present indefinite ?

Comment: @AbdulKaiumTanvir -- my response is in edit, but no, you cannot mix past and present like that.